# How to type static date into formula calculation?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to create a formula that calculates the number of hours based on the pricing at the time the job was done and the total cost of the job in Google Sheets. Unfortunately, I'm running into a #ERROR when I try to run it and I think it has something to do with how the Dates are typed in and not the logic of the nested IF statements. Any thoughts? Can add more information if needed.

`=IF((A2 >= 1/1/21 AND A2 <= 4/13/21), IF(E2 = "Elbow Grease", D2/165, D2/125), IF(E2 = "Elbow Grease", D2/195, D2/155))`

A2 would be formatted like `1/1/21`

E2 would be a string

D2 would be a numerical value (total cost)

Comment: you problem is both the string date and your use of `AND`.  It should be: `=IF(AND(A2 >= "1/1/21",A2 <= "4/13/21"),...`

Comment: @BigBen okay, then we are both correct:  `=IF(AND(A2 >= DATE(2021,1,1),A2 <= DATE(2021,4,13)),...`

Comment: also in Excel: `=IF(AND(A2 >= --"1/1/21",A2 <= --"4/13/21"),...` @BigBen

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=IF((A2 >= "1/1/21") * (A2 <= "4/13/21"), 
 IF(E2 = "Elbow Grease", D2/165, D2/125), 
 IF(E2 = "Elbow Grease", D2/195, D2/155))
```